# How can I determine the size of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

I tried this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int dime(int v[]){
    int i= sizeof v / sizeof *v;
    return i;
}

int main() {
    int v[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int i= dime(v);
    printf("The size of v is %d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

and it gives me that the size is 1, I also tried changing *v to v[0] and it didn't solve the problem... Can anyone help?

BTW don't know if it is useful (maybe just to know the size of an integer), but I'm running Eclipse in a Ubuntu 32-bit virtual machine.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't. Check the link Oli posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler has no knowledge of an array size when being passed as a pointer, only when being passed explicitly as an array. This would work:

```
int main() {
    int v[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int i = sizeof(v) / sizeof(*v);
    printf("The size of v is %d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should be `sizeof(v) / sizeof(int);`

Comment: @user384706: no. `sizeof(*v)` stays correct when `v` is changed to, say, a `long[10]`.

Comment: @user384706 No. sizeof(v)/sizeof(int) is more likely to be broken if you change the type from int, say, to char.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to put this in a function that gives me the length of the array?

Comment: No. You have to maintain a data type for storing the data as well as the array. Consider `struct data { int *values; size_t size };` -- of course now you'll have to write functions to create, modify and free such structures.

Comment: So I would define the struct data and then have my function "dime"?

Comment: @H2CO3:My point is that for someone who doesn't know that array is being passed as a pointer as the OP, the `sizeof(v) / sizeof(int);` is easy for him to undestand what is the problem and the solution. I don't think `sizeof(*v)` will get him very far in understanding what's going on (but coding in a general manner is a good thing I agree)

Comment: But if won't be usefult either, as the compiler won't have a clue about the size of the array.